# How can I set Expecto configuration properties when running tests via Visual Studio test adapter

Tags: f#, visual-studio-test-runner, expecto

I'm using Expecto.VisualStudio.TestAdapter to integrate with Visual Studio 2017. How do I set configuration options for Expecto so that the Visual Studio test runner will pick them up?

I specifically need to set parallel = false for a given test assembly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the code for the [Expecto Visual Studio Test Adapter](https://github.com/adamchester/expecto-adapter), I don't think you can.  At least, not without modifying the Test Adapter code and creating your own version.  Perhaps fork the project and create a Pull Request that allows the configuration to be tweaked.

The relevant section is in [Executor.fs](https://github.com/adamchester/expecto-adapter/blob/080d9e2081e07c5df7a716fc0b7b52de44674408/src/Expecto.VisualStudio.TestAdapter/Execution.fs) on line 160 (in the `ExecuteProxy` class).  It calls `runTests` with `{ defaultConfig with printer = testPrinters }`.  You could create your own `ExecuteProxy` class that takes the configuration to use when calling `runTests` as a parameter, and then create a generic version of `AssemblyExecutor` that takes a type parameter telling it what type of `ExecuteProxy` to use.